# xetex error when using resumecls with latexing

Tags: cv

I use Latexing with Sublime Text 3, and I have the following file:

```
\documentclass{resumecls}
\name{Jane Doe}
\address{Lorem ipsum \\ jane.doe@gmail.com}
\address{000-000-0000}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Compiling gives me the following error:

```
E: /usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty:4319 Wrong driver option `xetex',(hyperref) because XeTeX is not detected. \ProcessKeyvalOptions{Hyp}
```

I have no idea what to make of this. What could be the problem?

Comment: What happens when you "xetex" the document instead of "latex" it (as you wrote you would do)?

Comment: @Stephen I'm sorry, but I have no idea what xetex is. I was just trying to implement an online cv template.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XeTeX, i.e. instead of compiling with "latex document.tex" try "xetex document.tex" (or "xelatex  document.tex").

Comment: @Stephen I'm getting an error saying `! Undefined control sequence.` `l.1 \documentclass{resumecls}`

Comment: @Stephen Not `xetex`, but `xelatex`.

Comment: @egreg `xelatex` gives me `fontspec error: "!font-not-found"
! 
! The font "Adobe Song Std" cannot be found.`

Comment: @sodiumnitrate The `resumecls` class is Chinese oriented and it loads `ctex` which does the setting for fonts; unfortunately, the documentation of `ctex` is only in Chinese.

Comment: @egreg It's a really weird template I've found it seems :) I'll make my own. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @egreg: Yes, sure, me bad. (Just the wiki link is the same for XeTeX and XeLaTeX.)

Answer (score 1):

`resumecls` requires [XeLaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XeTeX) instead of LaTeX. As can be seen from the [description](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/resumecls) of the class, it

> pro­vides a sim­ple re­sumeé struc­ture that works, na­tively, with
>   both Chi­nese and English text

([ibid.](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/resumecls)). That requires at least one Chinese font, which obliviously is not installed at your system. Something from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fonts+installing might help with that, if you really want Chinese additional to English in your resume.